# How to set the value of the input name "PickupDate" using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have tried the following code but obtain an Object error:

```
Dim g As IHTMLElement

Set g = appIE.getElementsByName("PickupDate")
    g.Value = b

<div class="date date-time-field" id="pickup-date">
    <div class="date-icon icon"></div> 
    <input name="PickupDate" class="short picker__input" id="P666421526" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-readonly="false" aria-owns="P666421526_root" type="text" readonly="" placeholder="Date">
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Is this the expected output `P666421526`?

Comment: @shahin Yes that would be the output but the value of that ID changes. I am trying to set a date in a date picker.

Comment: I know that the value will change with different ID's. I'm gonna post an answer in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

For a particular value:

```
Set post = html.getElementsByName("PickupDate")
MsgBox post(0).ID
```

Looping through multiple values:

```
For Each post In html.getElementsByName("PickupDate")
    MsgBox post.ID
Next post
```